# Getting URL for the place using Google Places API

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

So I am able to successfully get a list of places but I just realized that the results do not contain the URL for the establishment. For e.g. I get Pizza Hut and the physical address for it but I do not get the URL for it (www.pizzahut.com). Is there a way to get this may be by doing an additional query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the external website is available for the place, it should be set in `website` in the query result.  If `url` is set, then that is the Google Place Page URL entered for the establishment.  The `reference` result may be used to query for the same place later. ([Documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details#PlaceDetailsResponses))

Comment: Ah I overlooked the link describing how to get details for each place.